# Set number of users

Tags: 7, users

I'm creating a site which give a set number of logins to each company who wants to use it.  For example, we give 20 logins to Company A.  What I want is when a user tries to create an account from the given company , if all the allowed slots are taken up they can't create an account.  At present I have a content type for Client, which has the client details and then a field for the number of 'licences' available.  Then when a user creates a new account they choose which client they are with. The site is built in Drupal 7

Is there a module out that which can already do this?

Thanks

Kieran

Comment: You'll need the OG module to create user groups, and you'll need the [og global limits](http://drupal.org/project/og_global_limits) to set the maximum number of users that can join a group, but its not available for d7 yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the main company as a user (ie Company A has an "*admin*" user account) then you could use [User Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships) and [User Relationship Limits](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationship_limits).  I suppose you could possibly use [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to create a new users whenever a company is created and tie the user to that content with either the [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) or [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module.

**[User Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships)**

> Admins create relationship types (friend, coworker, etc). Relationship
>   types can be setup to be one-way or mutual. If a relationship type is
>   one-way (subscriber) only the requester is shown as relating to the
>   requestee. Relationship types can also be set as needing or not
>   needing approval.

**[User Relationship Limits](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationship_limits)**

> User Relationship Limits extends User Relationships and provides the
>   ability for site administrators to limit the number of possible
>   relationships.